# sequelize.transaction is not a function

Tags: node.js, postgresql, transactions, sequelize.js, sails.js

I run 'npm install sequelize sqlite3' and 'yarn add sequelize sqlite3', my backend and front is running, but when i call my function this return an error "sequelize.transaction is not a function"

My function:

```
async sendorder(req, res){
    
    try{
      var sequelize = require('sequelize');

      const t = await sequelize.transaction();
     

      return res.ok({status: 200});
    }catch(err){
      return res.badRequest({err, status: 400})
    }
  }
```

if in console i run 'sequelize', this return  sequelize class: http://dontpad.com/sequelizeClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the Sequelize transaction you need to create a Sequelize instance using correct connection properties and then call `transaction` for this instance:

```js
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var sequelize = new Sequelize(connection_options)
const t = await sequelize.transaction();
```